# How to determine which rooms are effectively identical in a given maze

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, computer-science

The problem in question can be found [here](https://open.kattis.com/problems/maze)

TL;DR: 
There is a maze made up of circular rooms connected by indistinguishable corridors, the goal of players is to walk around and map out the whole maze.
Our goal is to look at a maze and try to reduce it as much as possible.
When looking at a maze you can compare two rooms A and B, if, when you are randomly dropped into the maze, you cannot tell whether you began in A or B these rooms are considered
effectively identical.
By running the maze through an algorithm we should be able to remove all effectively identical rooms thus making the maze smaller without affecting the overall feel of the maze to the players.
More details and rules are in the aforementioned document.

My intuition tells me to walk though the maze making a tree from every single node and then comparing the trees. I will include pictures for the given examples in the document.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVxHF.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AINzx.png)

Comment: Is brute force allowed?

Comment: It seems like most undirected graphs without self-loops and/or redundant edges are going to reduce to just a single node if removing identical nodes is repeated over and over. Rings, straight-lines, trees, fully connected graphs... repeatedly identify and remove nodes based only on being identical w.r.t. the tree isomorphism criterion and you end up with one node. It's the unexpected hanging problem.

Comment: @Rüzgar What do you mean is brute force allowed? The method I proposed is brute force-ish

Comment: @vik may be heuristic approach, but i commented before reading the original question so dont mind it. Your proposed method seems ok in a closed circuit, but i am curious and willing to see how you are going to handle the seperate circuits. I mean **"7,8,9"** and **"10,11,12,13"**. BTW, If and when you find a solution, I would be happy if you post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I feel, as does Patrick87 in the comments, that it seems likely that a simple graph will eventually be reduced to a single node. So as a frame challenge, I suggest not doing this! But if you want to, you're essentially asking to do a pile of graph isomorphisms, and so there's no better tool than [nauty](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/nauty/).*

So what you need to do is essentially (pseudocode):

```
reduce(G):
  for n1 in G.nodes:
    for n2 in G.nodes:
      if n1 != n2:
        let G1 = G
        swap G1[n1] and G1[n2]
        if nauty.isomorphic(G, G1):
          G.delete(n1) # or n2
          return G
  return G # G cannot be reduced
```

* Boost has an [isomorphism library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/graph/doc/isomorphism.html), but it is naive and very slow.